# Help with basic reading user input in C

Tags: c, input, integer

I am currently just learning C and for a project I need to read in integer inputs from the user. Currently I am using code that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int a, b;

    printf("Please enter your first number");
    while((a = getchar()) != '\n') {
    }

    printf("test");

    return 0;
}
```

Im not sure how to get the number with getchar and then store it in a variable i can use. 
Also I'm using = '\n' in the while statement because I don't really understand how EOF works (as in the K&R book) because whenever i use EOF i go into this loop i cant get out of.

Thanks for any advice anyone can offer.

Comment: `getchar` reads a `char`, as it's name indicates. Why would you expect it to read an `int`?

Comment: @Ken: Funny that it returns an `int`, eh? ;-) I think the key point is not the type it gets but the format of the data it accepts (character representing itself versus characters representing an integer in decimal notation).

Comment: @R. - that's what I was trying to say; you did it much better. :) Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use scanf.

Have a look at this example:

```
printf("Please enter your first number ");
int number=0;
scanf ("%d",&number);
```

Answer (score 0):

The scanf answer above mine is correct, but if you haven't read about addresses or format strings, it may be difficult to grok.

You can convert your character to its integer equivalent by subtracting '0' from it:

```
char c = getchar();
int n = c - '0';
```

Comment: Note: this subtracts the ascii value of '0' (which is 48), not the literal value zero.